# How can I get process list utilizing GPU with C#?

Tags: c#, process, opencl

I'm making my own process monitor and I would like to inquiry processes which are using GPU(CUDA/OpenCL for monitoring unintended execution of CryptoCoin miners.

I tried with `System.Management`, but I couldn't find any querystring for it.

What should I do for it? I googled several time for it, but no useful informations were found.

Comment: from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Oh, OK. I'll revise the question.

Comment: Nvidia provides such function in `nvml` libs. There are two main functions: `nvmlDeviceGetGraphicsRunningProcesses` and `nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses`. `nvml` is a cpp lib and no need to compile or link with cuda. Since I'm not familiar with c#/c++ interop, I can't give you a example here.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there any equivalent for AMD or Intel Graphics?

Comment: sry, I've no idea about them.

Comment: look at source code of codexl for amd. it can attach to processes and check what they do in opencl.

Comment: Oh great. Thank you.